# Has anyone heard of kickproof.com?

Tags: doors

I am wanting to reinforce our front and back door. I have researched the net and found kickproof.com, they manufacture the rebar door reinforcers that are kick in proof. Has anyone ever heard this company or had experience with their products?

Answer (score 3):

They sell an expensive version of a common product sold under a dozen different names, many of which can be found substantially cheaper at big box home improvement stores or even online.

Comment: It's also worth noting that in many areas, kick-ins are a vanishingly small percentage of total breakins, that simply having a properly-installed 1" deadbolt us enough to stop most kick-ins (don't forget to use a solidly made door and secure the strike properly to the framing), and generally that all most of us need is to be obviously one step more secure than our neighbors. Get local advice before assuming you need this.

Comment: Not to mention that a decent screen door is likely much more effective if locked. If you have to kick through something that is set in the jamb from the outside, you likely aren't going to get that far.  Oh look, is that a window?

Comment: I just fixed a kick-in last week. Solid core door that shattered at the lock. This product would not have availed me. Nor does any thing prevent someone with a crowbar from doing *anything*.